# Работа с anaconda внутри bash-script и gitlab-runner

Tags: python, bash, gitlab, anaconda, gitlab-runner

Как внутри gitlab-runner или bash-script можно запустить окружение [anaconda](https://www.google.com/search?q=anaconda&oq=anaconda%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i433j0j69i59l2j0j69i60j69i61.2487j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внутри bash-скрипта это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate temp
which python
```

Я точно не знаю, что обозначает первая строка. Но у меня это сработало. Взял я это [отсюда](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980).

Похожим образом можно завести всё внутри `.gitlab-ci.yml` (в моём случае, актуально, так как я использую shell-runner`)

```
stage:
  script:
    - /home/gitlab-runner/miniconda3/bin/conda create --name temp python=3.8 --yes
    - eval "$(/home/gitlab-runner/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
    - source activate temp
    - python --version
```

Comment: Если ты пытаешься написать документацию через метод "вопрос\ответ", то наверное стоит добавлять тег `faq`.

Comment: @donRumata при чём тут документация? Я фиксирую те проблемы, которые у меня возникли, если на их решение цходит более получаса. И пишу на них ответы. Не знаю, где Вы тут увидели документацию.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq

Comment: @donRumata спасибо, я знаю, что такое метки. На мой же вопос Вы не ответили.

Comment: При том, что описывание решений для возникших проблем - это как раз разновидность документации.

Comment: @donRumata с Вашими рассуждениями любой вопрос можно помечать как faq. За сим предлагаю закрыть дискуссию.